# as3 textinput capturing special characters

Tags: actionscript-3, special-characters, textfield

I'm trying textinput char code capture, but special characters dont work. Please some help

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

var dizi:Array = "şığ".split("");
tf.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, git);
function git(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    tf.restrict = dizi.toString();
    var harfsira:int= dizi.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode));
    trace(dizi.toString());
    trace(harfsira.toString());
    trace(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode.toString()));

}
```

"ş" key is pressed

```
ş,ı,ğ
-1
º
```

"ı" key is pressed

```
ş,ı,ğ
-1
i
```

"ğ" key is pressed

```
ş,ı,ğ
-1
Û
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual characters you are getting from the `String.fromCharCode(event.charCode.toString())` function do not match what is in your array. If you are indeed pressing the correct keys, you would need to change your array to:

```
var dizi:Array = "ºiÛ".split("");
```

to fix this inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you set the font to unicode Arial (it can handle special characters)?.

```
  var format_tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
  format_tf.font = "Arial"; //"Arial Unicode MS"
  format_tf.color = 0xFFFFFF; //white
  format_tf.size = 12; 

  tf.defaultTextFormat = format_tf;

  tf.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, git);
```

Or else my only experience of dealing with foreign & special characters is through byteArray. If the above doesn't work I will try to edit my answer to include converting via byteArray (note: not guaranteed to work or even time to do).